# memcached process memory is not decreasing even after eviction

Tags: caching, memory, amazon-ec2, memcached

I am running memcached in aws ec2 instance with total memory 61GB.

Memcached is started with the option -m 55000.

## echo "stats" | nc localhost 11211 | grep "STAT bytes \|STAT limit_maxbytes"

STAT limit_maxbytes 57671680000
STAT bytes 27307766965

The RSS memory used by memcached process 57349091328.

Initially the bytes used for cache was little less than the limit_maxbytes. But it did not start evicting (as the limit is not reached).

I wrote a script to manually evict the expired keys and the bytes used came down to 27307766965 bytes. But the RSS memory of memcached process is still high. It did not come down.

Can someone help me understand the behaviour.

Comment: do you get high concurrent connections? If I recall well, I have seen once an app not closing connections properly, which did take memory

Comment: Hi Tom, there are only around 1500 connections in memcache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Memcached daemon ever free() unused memory, without terminating the process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739990/can-a-memcached-daemon-ever-free-unused-memory-without-terminating-the-proces)